# c++ - caching objects

Tags: c++, caching

I have a `std::vector<Character*>` that will contain several different derived classes of `Character`, which i will just call `Enemy1`, `Enemy2`, and `Player` for the purpose of this question. I've seen other cases where someone has an array such as `Character characters[30]` but as I need polymorphism I don't think that will work for me (I could be wrong).

Essentially my question is of implementation, how can i set up/cache multiple characters for reuse in this way? I was looking at this (http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/object-pool.html), and i'm not sure if vectors can work in the same way. If one of the objects in the vector has been instantiated with `new Enemy1()` for example, can I later override it and set it to `new Enemy2()`? Should I have separate vectors/arrays for each enemy type?

Comment: Possible reference: http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/My-Favorite-Cpp-10-Liner

Comment: The probably better approach is `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Character>>` or `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Character>>`. See [Dynamic memory management](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory) please.

Comment: I watched the video, not bad actually, but doesn't calling the cache for an object that doesn't exist yet still require the same effort as instantiating an object with `new` and inserting it into the map?

Comment: How often are you adding and removing characters? Enough to warrant a pool? If this really is your bottleneck, consider putting effort into overloading new and then creating a memory pool for game entities/characters. As a side benefit, you would also gain ability to monitor heap allocation and track memory leaks.

Answer (score 0):

Accessing your characters from an `std::vector<Character*>` is possible. However to create data pools for your many possible character types you need separate vectors, usually*.

Check out this [Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27153573/how-can-implement-a-c-vector-that-points-to-other-multiply-typed-vectors) I asked recently. I got this [article](http://bannalia.blogspot.ca/2014/05/fast-polymorphic-collections.html) reference you might find useful.

*note: I believe that, with some tricks, it is possible to store various types in a single vector, as long as they all have the same size in memory.